# mysql fetch data from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

Please find picture to get more clarification on what I am asking
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYqnp.png)
Let me tell you full description

I have two tables -

Table1 contains `book_id` and `book_name`

second table -

Table2 contains `book_id`, `stock` and `cs_id`

I want when someone choose cs_id so result displayed in terms of book_name and not book_id

I'm sorry for short description...

I have two tables in `mysql` database -

```
    table1
SN  ID  Name
1   E-11    ELC
2   E-13    ELX
3   D-41    DME
```

and table2

```
SN  ID  CS_ID
1   E-11    C01
2   E-13    C01
3   D-41    C54
```

How to get result of all `name` from table1 using one `cs_id` from table2 using php.

Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Here what I'm using

```
$query = "SELECT table1.id, table2.name FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id WHERE table1.cs_id=$cs_id'
```

this is showing me 0 result.

Comment: you don't bother to spend time to learn. Just wanted result in quick time

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you want to do here.  Please show us your expected output.

Comment: Please do some sql tutorials in JOIN.

Comment: @Ravi That's not true...
Here is what I have done
$query = "SELECT table1.id, table2.name FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id WHERE table1.cs_id=$cs_id'";

Comment: @HarleyCBrown We wouldn't be aware until you share. right ?

Comment: I hope it is clear now

Comment: you describe 2 tables with 2 and 3 columns, but you are showing 2 tables with 3 columns. also, please provide an example (e.g. `$cs_id=...` should return `...`) of what you expect

Comment: As I created a query, I am showing users only cs_id in front. When an user select one of the cs_id, so data will be fetched from two tables associated with this cs_id.

for example - When I select cs_id=c01, so we have two ids E11, E13 with this cs_id in table 2.... Now I want to show the user name associated with these two ids from table1. Because I can't show user its id like E11, E12.

I meant result will display ELC and ELX. When Someone choose CS_ID=C01 instead of E11 and E13.

Answer (score 0):

Use TABLE LEFT JOIN 
LIKE

```
select tb1.name,tb2.ID FROM TABLE1 as tb1 LEFT JOIN TABLE2 as tb2 ON tb1.ID=tb2.ID where tb2.CS_ID='$request_id';
```

I hope its work